# Can I use Python 2.7 subprocess module from Python 2.6?

Tags: python, pip

Can I use Python 2.7 modules from Python 2.6?  Or do something to achieve the same effect?

I'm limited to use Python 2.6, but an [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue9127) exists in the `subprocess` module provided by Python 2.6.  This is fixed in Python 2.7.  I'm curious if I rig this up using pip (or equivalent) to sidestep the bug *temporarily* until upgrading one day.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What's the bug? There's probably a workaround that is easier than trying to mix Python versions (which, in general, is not possible).

Comment: It's not true that `subprocess` is written entirely in Python.  On Windows, there's also a [part written in C](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e0c353a43c7d/PC/_subprocess.c).

Comment: Bummer.  I'm referring to this issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue9127 (updated question, too).

Comment: It might just be easier to upgrade your problematic code than to downgrade an entire Python installation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etienne Perot suggested using a Python 3.2 subprocess backport available at http://code.google.com/p/python-subprocess32/ instead of hacking around the Python installation.

This let me install the module into my virtual environment's site-packages, and patch the subprocess code with http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/767420808a62 to fix the bug mentioned in question.  Afterwards, a simple `import subprocess32 as subprocess` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, usually. The difference between 2.6 and 2.7 isn't very big, as 2.7 is supposed to be a bridge between 2.6 and 3.0. As a result, most Python modules for 2.7 will work in both of these versions (usually better in 2.6 than 3.0).

Of course, the only surefire way to know the answer is to try!

**EDIT**: To be clear, I do not recommend that you do this at all, if you have a choice.
Hacking around a Python installation just because of a Python bug in one module is a bad idea.

Comment: I guess my question is, how would one achieve this?  I'm not as versed in Python packaging as I would like to be yet.

Comment: Just install the package the same way you would on Python 2.7. Usually `/usr/bin/python2.7 setup.py install` -> `/usr/bin/python2.6 setup.py install`. The only difference is the Python interpreter which you call to install the module. Certain modules may have extra installation instructions, for which you'll have to figure it out or post the name of the module in question (and if you have trouble installing it, that would probably have to go in another question)

Comment: If you are using `pip` to install packages, you can specify the Python environment to install packages using `--environment=/usr/bin/python2.6` or `--environment=/path/to/environment`.

Comment: Do you really think that it's plausible to replace a core module like subprocess so easily?

Comment: No, nor would I recommend that, but one of the `subprocess` alternatives might do the trick. For example, the `subprocess32` module: http://code.google.com/p/python-subprocess32/

Comment: What do you mean "nor would I recommend that". Your answer appears to do just that, or did I misinterpret you?

Comment: My answer attempts to answer the original question, which is whether it is possible to use a 2.7 Python module with 2.6. It doesn't say whether you should do that or not... until now, just edited it to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to stay on Python 2.6, but also want to fix this bug, I might suggest compiling Python 2.6 from source, but *also* applying the relevant bug fix code to the `subprocess` module from 2.7.

You will end up with a custom build of Python 2.6. Of course, if you're stuck on the standard 2.6 because you are unable to install *any* different version, then this won't help.